# bunifu Button Color Change on Click

Tags: c#, bunifu

while trying to change button color or border color on click with code below:

```
      private void LoggerStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (LoggerStart.Text == "Start")
            {
                //?
                LoggerStart.Text = "Stop";
                LoggerStart.IdleBorderColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                LoggerStart.Text = "Start";
            }
        }
```

the color changes for a short time, and returns to it's default color instantly!.

I expected to get the new color but it gets back to default shortly!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use other comparsion, ex. based on buttons color/border color

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (button1.ForeColor != Color.Green)
        {
            button1.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            button1.Text = "stop";
        }
        else
        {
            button1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            button1.Text = "start";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used LoggerStart.Idlefillcolor and it solved my problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).